# Scrolling inner div on key down and up

Tags: javascript, html

I have build an autocomplete container which displays the first four results and the rest are hidden and can be seen when scrolling the inner div element which holds all the results.

I have implemented the on key up when pressing the up and down keys in order to let the users navigate easily through the results but the inner div with the results isn't scrolling.

How can you scroll an element which has `overflow-y:hidden` and not the window ?

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/alonIL/kMzR9/)

In the example , just press any key inside the input box and use your arrows to go down, you will see that the div isn't scrolling

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some example code? Do you want a pure JS or a jQuery solution? Maybe you could post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Moob, I've added a jsFiddle

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can update your script to find the relative position of the selected element and scroll to it:

```
$(".someInput").on("keyup", function(e) {
   $(".wrapper").show(); 
    if (e.which == 40) {
        $('.element:not(:last-child).element-hover').removeClass('element-hover').next().addClass('element-hover');
    } else if (e.which == 38) {
        $('.element:not(:first-child).element-hover').removeClass('element-hover').prev().addClass('element-hover');    
    }
    //scroll to element:
    $(".wrapper .inner_div").scrollTop(0);//set to top
    $(".wrapper .inner_div").scrollTop($('.element-hover:first').offset().top-$(".wrapper .inner_div").height());//then set equal to the position of the selected element minus the height of scrolling div
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kMzR9/3/

Answer (score 10):

By using `tabIndex="-1"` attribute on each of the children of a container, the browser will automatically scroll the container to have the child with the current focus in-view.

### Demo (vanilla javascript):

```js
var listElm = document.querySelector('ul')

// Mark first list item
listElm.firstElementChild.focus()

// Event listener
window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)

// Event callback
function onKeyDown(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  
  var selectedElm = document.activeElement,
      goToStart,
      // map actions to event's key
      action = {ArrowUp:"previous", Up:"previous", ArrowDown:"next", Down:"next"}

  selectedElm = selectedElm[action[e.key] + "ElementSibling"];

  // loop if top/bottom edges reached or "home"/"end" keys clicked
  if( !selectedElm || e.key == 'Home' || e.key == 'End' ){
    goToStart = action[e.key] == "next" || e.key == 'Home'
    selectedElm = listElm.children[goToStart ? 0 : listElm.children.length - 1]
  }
  
  selectedElm.focus()
}
```

```css
ul{ 
  list-style: none; 
  border    : 1px solid silver; 
  max-height: 170px;
  padding   : 0;
  margin    : 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth; /* nice smooth movement */
  overflow  : hidden;      /* set to hidden by OP's request */
}

li{ padding:.5em; margin:0; }
li:focus{ background:LIGHTSALMON; outline:none; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 1</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 2</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 3</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 4</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 5</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 6</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 7</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 8</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 9</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 10</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 11</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 12</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 13</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 14</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1">item 15</li>
</ul>
```

To make this list accessible (*ARIA*) [read this](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/web_EN/exemples/check-listbox/index.html)

Comment: This solution works like a charm no script required at all. Just tabIndex did the job

Comment: Your fix made me cry, simple and awesome.

Comment: Can you please tell me what means by action[e.key] == "next" ? there is no next key on doc.

Comment: @ShashankBhatt - I mapped key names to action names, to know which key does what action. The code is self-explanatory

Comment: @vsync oh ya sorry you mean its down or arrowdown rt? got it now thanks for the nice solution.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to implement it. and the exact solution for you need to consider your context.

Anyway, one possible solution is to use in the **container** div '**position: relative**' and in the **inner** div (which hold the content) use '**position: absolute**' and '**top: 0px**'.
When user press on the up/down arrows you changing the top property accordingly.

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function moveContent(px) {
    var top = $('.content').position().top;
    $(".content").css("top", top+px);
}

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
       moveContent(-5);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       moveContent(5);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        hello 1<br/>
        hello 2<br/>
        hello 3<br/>
        hello 4<br/>
        hello 5<br/>
        hello 6<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

See my example in: http://jsfiddle.net/Kq2Qq/3/

Answer (score 3):

Two years passed... just in case someone stumbles over this, like me. In addition to the last two lines in Moobs answer (can't do any comments yet...), plain Javascript:

(Left out: how to get elements in pure JS), then:

`$innerDiv.scrollTop = $hoveredElement.offsetTop - $innerDiv.clientHeight;`

There also seems to be no need to "reset" `scrollTop` to zero before assigning the new value

Comment: Cool, it works. but you may also want add the hoveredElement's height to make it visible. `$innerDiv.scrollTop = $hoveredElement.offsetTop + $hoveredElement.clientHeight - $innerDiv.clientHeight;`

Answer (score 1):

Recently I faced the same problem and solved it by using .*emphasized text*scrollIntoView(), sample code is below. Example of two function respectively for up arrow key and down arrow key

```
moveUp: function(e) {
        if (current > 0) {
            current--;
            var allNOdes = document.getElementById('list').childNodes;
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (allNOdes[current]) {
                allNOdes[current].scrollIntoView(true);
            }
        }
    },
    moveDown: function(e) {
        if (current <  10) {
            current++;
            var allNOdes = document.getElementById('list').childNodes;
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (allNOdes[current]) {
                allNOdes[current].scrollIntoView(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Initially define current as 0
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="result" id="list">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.result{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `scrollIntoView()` is solution for me :)