# how to obtain scroll to view inside a div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am having a input box and search results div, whenever i type something i am able to see the results but when i do the navigation through keys the scroll to view is not happening.

how can i achieve this. I have created the working example in [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-qh3jh).

scenario

1. type "1" in input box
2. click on down arrow key upto 3rd element you will be able to see red color css as highlight but after that the navigation
   is going on but the scroll is not happening

any help appreicated

Comment: i think i need to use scrollintoView api, but how should i use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268193/scrolling-inner-div-on-key-down-and-up

Comment: but this one is jquery solution. but here how i should target with ref or something

Comment: any idea or any thoughts on how to solve this one

Comment: Where exactly are you expecting it to scroll to?

Comment: which ever is having the active. so i am thinking shall i take getElementByClassNames and target active and make scroll to that particular class will it work. Also one more doubt i have whenever i start typing the first search result is higlighted is it because i am setting cursor in state as zero

Comment: I would avoid doing any sort of DOM manipulation like getElementByClassNames to target a particular element in React. Instead you should try integrate a ref system. I'm trying to create a sandbox for you at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your updated sandbox friend: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-5fvk9

The main thing I added was a `ref` creating logic.

In the component and outside render(), we define an array to keep track of all our refs.

```
  itemRefs = []
```

That array gets populated in .map() by passing in the ref prop available in each tag.

```
{searchResults.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li
         ref={ref => (this.itemRefs[index] = ref)}
         onClick={() => this.goToItem(index)}
         className={cursor === index ? 'active' : null}
      >
        <label className="first-lb">{item.id}</label>
        <label className="second-lb">{item.name}</label>
        <label className="third-lb">{item.address}</label>
      </li>
    )
})}
```

Then we have an onClick-handler that accepts a ref index, which we use to scroll into that selected item.

```
  goToItem = index => {
    if (this.itemRefs[index]) {
      this.itemRefs[index].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', nearest: "block"})
    }

    this.setState({
      cursor: index,
    })
  }
```

Additionally, to handle the scroll events on arrow-key down and arrow-key up.

```
  _keyDownOnSearchResults = e => {
    const {cursor, searchResults} = this.state
    if (e.keyCode === 38 && cursor > 0) {
      this.itemRefs[cursor - 1].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        nearest: 'block',
      })
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        cursor: prevState.cursor - 1,
      }))
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40 && cursor < searchResults.length - 1) {
      this.itemRefs[cursor + 1].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        nearest: 'block',
      })
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        cursor: prevState.cursor + 1,
      }))
    }
  }
```

Comment: i checked it, i am not able to see the 4th result when i use down arrow key

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS that's so strange, I'm able to see it just fine. You mean, if I type something and get back 4+ results, then select the 4th item, it does not scroll to it?

Comment: Yes that's the problem, I will create a repo and share you the code. Can you check that one may be any issue with codesandbox.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS oh I understand what you're saying now. Specifically clicking the down key does not move the position of the scrolling. Not clicking on the item. my bad.

Comment: @ Christopher Ngo i have created the codesandbox and i have working one with all my doubts in here. Can you check and let me know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916802/search-results-highlight-results-using-reactjs

Comment: @ Christopher are you able to understand my doubts what i have asked for in that question

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yeah I understand what the problem you're having is :). I've created a new sandbox. See updated solution.

Comment: @ christopher thank you very much. Can you check this one also. It will be very helpful what am i missing there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916802/search-results-highlight-results-using-reactjs

Comment: @ christopher because the hover is making a problem either arrow key or hover should work at a time

Comment: I see, then you need to get creative with your classes as well. Let me see what I can do it to fix that